# "c.defaultView.getComputedStyle() is null" issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, iframe, cross-domain

I'm using jquery in a page on domain "abc.com", and this page opens an iframe on domain "def.com", which also uses jquery (same version, and I tried different ones from 1.5.2 to 1.6.4). The frame is opened using the jquery library [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) (not maintained anymore...).

My problem occurs in Firefox (any version from 3.X to 8.0), where I get the javascript error "c.defaultView.getComputedStyle(a, null) is null" the first time I load the iframe, and thus can't access any jquery initialization method:

```
$(function() {
  /* Does not pass here in firefox */
});
```

On any other browser (chrome, ie, opera...) the code works, but in firefox I have to reload manually the iframe (right click -> this frame -> reload)... I have read some posts here on SO about similar issues, and each time the problem is a conflict between the two jquery libraries. In my case I can't remove one of the JS because the two pages are on different domains.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This is related to the following Firefox bug:

[Bug 548397 - window.getComputedStyle() returns null inside an iframe with display: none](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=548397)

Possible solutions include setting the iframe's width and height to 0 or visibility to hidden, rather than using `display: none`.